# Partition is invisible in Windows after formatting during Ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning

I was installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, and I tried to allocate all of my `F:` drive (about 400GB) to Ubuntu by formatting it as EXT2.

However, it was taking a bit long for my liking, so I canceled the operation and rebooted into Windows, but my `F:` drive is no longer there. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat the disk in Windows to make it reappear as a drive in Windows Explorer. This is done with the Disk Management tool.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `diskmgmt.msc` to launch the Disk Management tool. Select the disk containing the old `F:\` partition and then right-click the partition. Click "Format..." and complete the formatting process:

[image: Screenshot of disk management]

Comment: But I have some of my data in the drive

Comment: How could you have data on the drive if it was formatted during the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: No I didn't formated it

Comment: @user47 When you start to change a partition type (like you did in install to convert your F drive to EXT2), it has to format the drive before it can use it. There's very likely nothing on that drive anymore that can be saved.

Comment: Once the partition has been formatted (even partially) the chance of recovering data from it is extremely slim.

Comment: There was an option for format partition or not so I didn't formated it

Comment: @user47 Doesn't matter -- filesystem conversions still erase critical records that make recovery near impossible, especially if let run for a long time.

Comment: But I can see used space of that  drive when trying to reinstalling it

Comment: Well it is now showing that drive /dev/sda4  as ext2 type and others as ntfs like before

Comment: Can anyone tell what to do now stick with installation or should I go for gparted installation by trying ubuntu option

Comment: If you have data on the partition that Ubuntu can see, by all means, use the LiveCD to copy the data off the partition. Personally, I don't see how anything other than what was half-installed could be on the partition anyway.